# Networkmanager shows no Wifi, nor proper ethernet connection

Tags: networking, network-manager

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 today through minimal-install. At first my networking was ok (after installing `network-manager`), but now I have no internet. I only did some theming and installed a few applications, didn't fiddle with my networking. When I open my nm-applet I see this:
[image]

After a short search I managed to get my ethernet to work, through editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (`managed=true`)

[image]

However, my wireless networks are still unavailable, and the ethernet doesn't have its proper name.

Does anyone know what might have gone wrong and how can I fix this?

**Outputs**

`ifconfig -a`

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:29:a6:09:43:7f  
          inet addr:192.168.14.114  Bcast:192.168.14.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd40:8668:4fd2:0:a2ed:73e9:6ae0:7113/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6345:48a5:9afe:87eb/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd40:8668:4fd2:0:11b7:96f8:d04:559d/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3969 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2702203 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:625937 (625.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:40921 (40.9 KB)  TX bytes:40921 (40.9 KB)
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` (haven't touched that since installation):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface enp1s0 inet6 auto
```

Comment: I don't believe minimal install includes Network Manager by default and so depends on the configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces`. If you wish to instead use NM, it will be necessary to de-populate the interfaces file. Please edit your question to add the result of `cat /etc/network/intefaces` and we'll get started. Your `ifconfig` file looks like you are connected perfectly. By the way, your ethernet *is* named correctly; please see: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: Thank you, I'm just used to the name of the network appearing, instead of (`ifupdown(enp1s0)`). I don't care too much if it stays and everything is functional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Network Manager to take over all interfaces correctly, remove the ethernet settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Next, return NetworkManager.conf to its default state where managed=false.

Finally, restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It may take a reboot.

As for the wireless, I suggest that you start a new question and include the diagnostic report as described here. [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180)